# How to check the Temp table count in informix

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix, temp-tables

How to check the Temp table has rows in  `informix`  like

i check the datatable in c#

```
if( dt != null && dt.rows.count >0)
{
   //------
}
```

---

i want to do like the previous check in my informix stored procedure temp table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_table_1234
```

In stored procedures and triggers you can use it like:

```
... 
for each row
    when (select count(*) from my_temp_table > 1) ...
```